# Wicket: resource path sounds not working

Tags: javascript, path, wicket

I have some trouble with a path...
I'm using wicket, and I have a sounds folder on Web Pages folder.

I'm using this path on javascript code, to reproduce the sounds:

```
      audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sounds/startMusic.mp3');
```

but it doesn't play the sound.

I took the example from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamiehap/jtCA9/12/) but I changed the path, from one absolute to the relative one (using the absolute, works).

Where is my mistake?
Looking for the path on internet, I found out that everybody use this one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you need to rewrite the path to make it context-relative. Try to use UrlUtils to get the context relative path:

```
UrlUtils.rewriteToContextRelative("sounds/startMusic.mp3", RequestCycle.get()));
```

Comment: Using wicket, my problem was solved with ../../path.